# The value 'hours:minutes AM/PM' is not valid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Telerik's timepicker in an MVC razor view.

```
@(Html.Kendo().TimePicker()
  .Name("StartTime")
  .HtmlAttributes(new { title = "Start Time" })
  .DateInput()
  .Interval(15)
 )
```

By default, it renders like this

[image]

In the viewmodel class, I have defined StartTime as nullable type (public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }). Users may choose not to fill the timepicker.

In the controller, when I am checking if ModelState is valid, if the user doesnt fill the timepicker, the ModelState is invalid and the ModelState error is

```
The value 'hours:minutes AM/PM' is not valid for Start Time
```

Comment: Well, the solution would be to achieve an empty value for `start time` input if user doesn't specify time. But I don't know how to do it with **Telerik**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the    `.DateInput()`    to be like:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TimePicker()
.Name("StartTime")
.HtmlAttributes(new { title = "Start Time" })
.Interval(15)
)
```

and check if the problem is solved.